# oracle sql query months

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm fairly new to SQL and I have a question regarding a query.
I would like to use a "with-clause" to create a temporary table that displays all months between two dates.
I will then use this temporary table to apply a filter to my actual table.
My query:

```
  WITH  monlist(mon, next_mon) as ( 
select add_months(trunc(to_date(:P6_DATUM_VON,'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'MM'), level - 1), add_months(trunc(to_date(:P6_DATUM_VON,'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'MM'), level)    
from dual
connect by level <= (months_between(to_date(:P6_DATUM_BIS,'DD-MM-YYYY'), to_date(:P6_DATUM_VON,'DD-MM-YYYY')))
```

The problem is that I want to narrow it down to days, i.e. if I want to start from 05-01-2022 (DD-MM-YYY), this is not possible.
The temporary table starts with the beginning of the month (01-01-2022).
It is similar with the end - it is rounded up to the full month.
Is there a way to change the query so that the initial and final values are accepted correctly?

I would like to get the following output:

```
mon          next_mon
05-01.2022 - 01-02-2022
01-02-2022 - 28-02-2022

...
01-10-2022 - 15-10-2022 (If end-date is 15-10-2022)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it were PL/SQL, you'd use `IF-THEN-ELSE`; in SQL, use CASE expression. Something like this (example ran in SQL*Plus, hence substitution variables):

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd-mm-yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> set ver off
SQL>
SQL> WITH monlist as
  2    (select add_months(trunc(to_date('&&P6_DATUM_VON','DD-MM-YYYY'), 'MM'), level - 1) mon,
  3            add_months(trunc(to_date('&&P6_DATUM_VON','DD-MM-YYYY'), 'MM'), level) next_mon,
  4            level lvl
  5     from dual
  6     connect by level <= months_between(to_date('&&P6_DATUM_BIS','DD-MM-YYYY'),
  7                                        to_date('&&P6_DATUM_VON','DD-MM-YYYY')
  8                                       ) + 1
  9    )
 10  select case when lvl = 1
 11                   then to_date('&&P6_DATUM_VON','DD-MM-YYYY') else mon      end mon,
 12         case when lvl = (select max(lvl) from monlist)
 13                   then to_date('&&P6_DATUM_BIS','DD-MM-YYYY') else next_mon end next_mon
 14  from monlist
 15  order by lvl;
Enter value for p6_datum_von: 05-01-2022
Enter value for p6_datum_bis: 15-10-2022
```

---

```
MON        NEXT_MON
---------- ----------
05-01-2022 01-02-2022
01-02-2022 01-03-2022
01-03-2022 01-04-2022
01-04-2022 01-05-2022
01-05-2022 01-06-2022
01-06-2022 01-07-2022
01-07-2022 01-08-2022
01-08-2022 01-09-2022
01-09-2022 01-10-2022
01-10-2022 15-10-2022

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

In Apex (you do use it, right? Regarding :P6_... item names?), that would be just

```
WITH monlist as
  (select add_months(trunc(to_date(:P6_DATUM_VON,'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'MM'), level - 1) mon,
          add_months(trunc(to_date(:P6_DATUM_VON,'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'MM'), level) next_mon,
          level lvl
   from dual
   connect by level <= months_between(to_date(:P6_DATUM_BIS,'DD-MM-YYYY'),
                                      to_date(:P6_DATUM_VON,'DD-MM-YYYY')
                                     ) + 1
  )
select case when lvl = 1
                 then to_date(:P6_DATUM_VON,'DD-MM-YYYY') else mon      end mon,
       case when lvl = (select max(lvl) from monlist)
                 then to_date(:P6_DATUM_BIS,'DD-MM-YYYY') else next_mon end next_mon
from monlist
order by lvl;
```

Comment: Thanks for supporting! Yes I'm using oracle APEX. The output looks really good - but there is still one problem left. Is it possible to get the last output like this: `01-09-2022 - 01-10-2022 & 01-10-2022 - 15-10-2022` ?

Comment: Yes; add 1 month (in line #8)